# $X$ is a Topology. For every two elements $x, y∈X$ there is some function $f : X → \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$, then $X$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

I am working on this problem:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose that for every two elements $x, y ∈ X$ there is
> some function $f : X → \mathbb{R}$ so that $f (x) = 0$ and $f (y) = 1$, then $X$ is Hausdorff. (Here $\mathbb{R}$ has
> the usual Euclidean topology.)

I can assume that $x\neq y$ since I am trying to prove $X$ is Hausdorff and $x = y$ is not of interest. The points $1$ and $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ have mutually disjoint open sets around them, but the function is not continuous so I can't use theorems that connect $\mathbb{R}$ to the preimage.
I have theorems from my munkres book about the implications from spaces being Hausdorff, but no theorems that imply a space is Hausdorff. So my only strategy that I can see is to show open sets containing $x$ and $y$ in $X$ are mutually disjoint.

But I am given so little to work with, other that I can declare $x$ and $y$ to be in $X$, put them in open sets because $X$ is a toplogical space, and use properties of a topology. I have been working on this for some time, can you please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Separate $0$ and $1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ by the Hausdorff condition, then pull those open sets back to open sets in $X$.

Comment: The Urysohn Function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma

Comment: In general, you just need that the codomain is Hausdorff, it doesn't need to be $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the proof:

Let $x\neq y\in X$ be distinct points. By assumption, we have $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$. Consider the preimages $f^{-1}((-1/2,1/2))$ and $f^{-1}((1/2,3/2))$. By the definition of continuity, $f^{-1}((-1/2,1/2))$ is an open set containing $x$, and $f^{-1}((1/2,3/2))$ is an open set containing $y$. These sets are moreover disjoint. Hence, we have found disjoint neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$, so by definition we conclude that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Note: If we weren't allowed to assume that $f$ was continuous, then the existence of such functions $f$ would be trivial and give no information. Given $x,y\in X$, we can define $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=0$, and $f(z)=1$ for all $z\neq x$. This is well defined and has the desired property that $f(y)=1$. This gives a philosophical reason for why you were making no progress without this assumption.

Comment: Thank you Milo Moses. I had two documents with the question, but one had a typo and omitted the fact that the function is continuous.